# simple back button in windows 10 xaml app

Tags: xaml

I would like to place a back button in the top left of my W10 app but I have no idea how to do that. In VS2013 I used the basic template with it´s back button, but there is no template in VS2015. (I know about the template10 Project on github but I didn´t get it work). 
I think there must be a simple 1-line xaml command to place the typical looking Windows App back button. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you call that XAML Page as a NavigationPage, then it will automatically render with the default back links. This can be done in the C#:

```
new NavigationPage (new YourPage);
```

see this microsoft [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) for some examples and background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read the MS page but I must admit that I still don´t understand how to do. 
When i added your line to the page nothing happened. What have should happen? Should the button appear automatically?

Comment: There is an appbar button in VS2015 and I can select an arrow as icon for it. But it doesn´t really look like the well known back button.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in back button functionality for Windows 10 application like the back button we see in the **Store** Application, there's a back button at the top left corner of the window beside the title bar.

You can try to put this in your code behind or in your NavigatedTo() method.

```
   if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
   else
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
```